# how to limit GET access to resources using DjangoAuthorization() in tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I am using tastypie to create a RESTful API.  I have hit a snag with limiting user authorization based on the django admin permissions.  [Per the docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authorization.html#djangoauthorization), I am trying to implement `DjangoAuthorization()`.

```
class myResource(ModelResource):
   class Meta:
      queryset = myModel.objects().all()
      allowed_methods = ['get','post']
      authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
      authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
```

Currently, a user `fakeuser` with no Django permissions at all on `myModel` can still GET data from the api. This user is appropriatly restricted from POSTing data.

#### tl;dr How can I extend the DjangoAuthorization() class to restrict GET for users with no Django permisions on a model

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write your own Authorization Backend extending from `DjangoAuthorization` which overrides access methods according to your criteria, one example of how to override the `read_detail` (GET) method below:

```
from tastypie.authorization import DjangoAuthorization
from tastypie.exceptions import Unauthorized

class CustomDjangoAuthorization(DjangoAuthorization):

    def read_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
        result = super(CustomDjangoAuthorization, self).read_detail(object_list, bundle)

        # now we check here for specific permission
        if not bundle.request.user.has_perm('any_permission'):
            raise Unauthorized("You are not allowed to access that resource.")

        return result
```

Now use `CustomDjangoAuthorization` class in your resource:

```
class myResource(ModelResource):
   class Meta:
      queryset = myModel.objects().all()
      allowed_methods = ['get','post']
      authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
      authorization = CustomDjangoAuthorization()
```

Comment: This looks great!  Will try it out tomorrow.